# Adding new frames to a mobile app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am planning to create a mobile app (android). It has several pages/frames for different cases. Now the number of frames/pages that I would like the app to have would grow over time, so new frames/pages would keep on adding.

Now, I have two options the way I see it. One being keep on adding new version of the app with new pages/frames once every few months. Other being I decide upfront all the possible templates for those frames. Once the templates are fixed, the response (from REST API containing data to display) would also contain the information of which template to use. I could embed the logic on how to interpret the template type available in response in the app code, so the app knows how to display a template of type "table" and what constitutes the table headers, etc.

The caveat for former approach (upgrade) is that once in while, app needs to be upgraded, something which not all users would like to do. A way around it is to enforce an upgrade, which renders app unusable. The problem with the latter approach (template) is that a lot more code needs to be written to make it work right.

I would like to know what approach is mostly used, and whether there are popular apps out there which use the latter (template) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely recommend using the first approach (that is, you submit updates when you actually provide new versions of the app...).

Here are a few reasons which seem to be enough to choose the regular option:

- If you use the templates, you are "forcing" updates to the user. One day he has a UI, and the next he has another one (new element in the menu, or new display of a known activity/fragment). And that's worse, because he didn't receive a notification that there was a new version of the app. So he might actually get confused.
- You are relying on a web connection to perform this check. So you don't even get the guarantee that this will work (depending on the permissions and business of your app, this argument may be invalid for your particular case. I wanted to answer to the general question though).
- You will add a ton of complexity to your application's code (meaning no offense, I doubt you can think up-front about ALL the designs/renderings you will need in the coming months/years). And a higher complexity = more bugs, statistically.

Do you realize that the second approach you are talking about is more or less the principle of a website? Maybe what you are looking for is a simple app which has a webview to your mobile website?

Comment: Yes, @jbedon, what you've said is exactly what I was thinking, just wanted to get expert opinion..